# Isomorphism for invertible diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-groups

We know that the set of invertible diagonal $n\times n$ matrix  over $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ ($\mathrm{DL}(n,q)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,q)$). Is there any isomorphism for $\mathrm{DL}(n,q)$?
I think $\mathrm{DL}(n,q)$ is isomorphic to product of $\mathrm{GF}(q)^\times$ $n$ times to itself. But I can't prove it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if $K$ is any field, then the subgroup of diagonal matrices of $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ is isomorphic to $(K^*)^n$. The isomorphism maps $(\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n) \in (K^*)^n$ to the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The diagonal matrix
$$
\operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n) = \begin{bmatrix} d_1 & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & d_n \end{bmatrix} \in M_n(GF(q))
$$
is invertible if and only if each $d_i \in GF(q)^\times$ since
$$
\operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n) \operatorname{diag}(d'_1, \ldots, d'_n) = \operatorname{diag}(d_1 d'_1, \ldots, d_n d'_n).
$$
Now, the map
$$
\begin{align}
DL(n, q) &\to GF(q)^\times \times \cdots \times GF(q)^\times \\
\operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n) &\mapsto (d_1, \ldots, d_n)
\end{align}
$$
is the required isomorphism.  Note that this argument works for any field.